# typescript generics function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Need to write such interface Object with generic in such way, that function1 and function2 will work with this object. Uncomment 1st fn, then uncomment 2nd

```
// function1
type Language = "en" | "de";

function showInConsole(value: Language) {
  console.log("language");
}

// function2
// type Country = "it" | "gb";

// function showInConsole(value: Country) {
//   console.log("country");
// }

interface Object {
  showInConsole: <Value>(value: Value)=>void;
}

const obect: Object = {
  showInConsole
}
```

here is the playground to see issue
[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/PTAEDMEsCcGcBcIFcB2BjekD2KBQ8BPABwFNQAZAQxQHMlKayBeUAIhJVdAB82ATEqwDcuXOFQZsKULAAWWAO4BJFAGEcsLABsSACgBulLUhIAuCtToMSASlABvXKFBoN2kgDotWGrtZbLekZWGxEAX1EQGRJXFD5kdEwcXCjCUlB1VHhoAlAWVkh4Ll5WGgAjYUiwcUSpGXllNTcdAyMTc0yUbII7RyjnWM0dLx8-ANogwVCUsAjcSC6SaHBKNDIAeTKAKxjER2c5RRV1FCGzUAAeADU2kgA%20VuNzm6ebJjv9LEg%20cNFBxCwZV25k2OwweQcTnqRyap3cuDCQA)

Comment: types in value can be not Language and Country but smth else, thats why i cant use extends Language | Country

Comment: no iin value can be number, either another unknown Type etc...

Comment: So, perhaps `interface MyObject<T> { showInConsole: (value: T) => void; }` ? Or do you really want to extend the predefined `Object` type?

Comment: The most natural answer is use a union `showInConsole: ((value: Language) => void) | ((value: Country) => void)` and I can't think of another way that would make any sense. If you want `showInConsole` to be able to accept any other type apart from `Language` or `Country` then it is basically `showInConsole: (value: any) => void`. How are you planning to use this?

Comment: @AlexR hm its good solution, maybe will be the best way, thanks